# How disable formatting for specific line

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Emacs 27

In my org file I has smt like this:

```
global-ignores = .idea .settings .project *.iml my*.sh *.ipr *.iws
```

Result:

[image]

Is it possible to ignore formatting ONLY in this line?
I need to show asteriks in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a : at the start of line which indicates, in org, that the remainder of the line is not to be interpreted.